# Заполнение массива поочередно положительными и отрицательными числами

Tags: java, массивы, core

Как заполнить массив не просто рандомными числами, а положительными и отрицательными целыми числами (-10,10) по очереди через пробел, без повторов?
Т.е. на выходе должно быть:
5 -8 1 -3 0 -7 2

Comment: то есть числа в массиве должны быть рандомные от -10 до 10?

Comment: Ну всё таки попытайтесь приложить хоть какой-то код, потому что мы не понимаем, в чём именно у вас проблемы, в рандоме, в выводе или в чём? Если вообще нет мыслей, то начните с main метода, а если и с ним проблемы, то лучше прочитать книгу или пройти курсы по основам Java, прежде чем приступать к решению таких задач.

Comment: Попытайтесь хоть что-то написать, пусть даже просто вывод рендомных чисел через пробел без очередности, а иначе это прямое нарушение правил форума. Поставлю голос "за" чтобы снизить вероятность удаления вопроса, дабы поддержать вас в поиске решения задачи

Comment: Заводите 2 списка со всеми возможными значениями(список положительных и отрицательных). Выдёргиваете случайные элементы из этих списков по очереди, формируете из них новый список

Comment: @bhxbr922 Я знаю чем отличается. Хамством участников с низкой репутацией.

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев а почему вы решили, что 8 - это ошибка?

Comment: @vp_arth, эмм, возможно я случайно стёр 8 и дописал другую цифру, ничего страшного ведь это просто пример 

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев спасибо за правки!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Без уникальности

https://ideone.com/7nHwSN

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int a[] = new int[rand.nextInt(10) + 6];
    for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) a[q] = 1 + rand.nextInt(9);
    for (var q=1; q<a.length; q+=2) a[q] = -a[q];
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}
```

## С уникальностью

Конечно, можно было сделать асимптотически оптимальнее, но для 10 и так хорошо.

https://ideone.com/lgV9AK

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int MAX = 10;
    boolean pos[] = new boolean[MAX+1];
    boolean neg[] = new boolean[MAX+1];

    int a[] = new int[rand.nextInt(10) + 6];
    
    for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
      var x = 1 + rand.nextInt(MAX - (q >> 1));
      var used = (q & 1) == 0 ? pos : neg;
      
      for (var w=0; w<=x; ++w) {
        if (used[w]) {
          ++x;
        }
      }

      used[x] = true;
      a[q] = (q & 1) == 0 ? x : -x;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}
```

Comment: Как быть с «без повторов»?

Comment: @vp_arth, тьфу. Надо было внимательно читать вопрос.

Comment: @vp_arth, дополнил, теперь они уникальны.

Comment: Как интересно у вас `q/2` записано)

Comment: @vp_arth, интереснее что у меня половина переменных через `var`, а я об этом задумался только имея рабочий код))

Comment: Спасибо за решение (хоть оно для меня и тяжеловато пока) и советы, понятно в какую сторону думать!

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе не указан размер массива, по этому будем считать его рандомным от 0 до 21

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
      //минимальное значение в массиве
      int minVal = -10;
      //максимальное значение в массиве
      int maxVal = 10;
      //максимальный размер массива = 21
      int listSize = (int) (Math.random() * 22);
      //будем чередовать отрицательные числа, начнем с положительного
      boolean negative = false;
      //заполняем массив покуда его размер не составит listSize
      while (resultList.size() != listSize) {
          //получаем число от minVal до maxVal
          int k = minVal + (int) (Math.random() * (maxVal + 1));
          //если 0 и 0 уже есть в массиве - пропускаем ход
          if (k == 0 && resultList.contains(k))
              continue;
          //поочередно добавляем отрицательные/положительные числа 
          //и проверяем нет ли их в массиве
          if (negative) {
              if (!resultList.contains(-k)) {
                  resultList.add(-k);
                  negative = false;
              }
          } else {
              if (!resultList.contains(k)) {
                  resultList.add(k);
                  negative = true;
              }
          }
      }
      //выводим результат
      System.out.println(resultList);
    }
}
```

Думаю с выводом результата **через пробел** разберетесь

**UPD** иной вариант на котлине *(дело было вечером, делать было нечего)*

```
//создаем набор положительных чисел
val posArr = (1..10).toMutableList()
//создаем набор отрицательных чисел
val negArr = (-10..0).toMutableList()
//начинаем с положительных
var pos = true
//заполняем и выводим массив величиной от 0 до 21
println(IntArray((0..21).random()) {
    var k = 0
    if (pos) {
        k = posArr.get((0..posArr.size - 1).random())
        posArr.remove(k)
    } else {
       k = negArr.get((0..negArr.size - 1).random())
       negArr.remove(k) 
    }
    pos = !pos
    k
}.asList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Чуть проще и быстрее, чем предложенные варианты

```
Set<Integer> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Random random = new Random();
int lowerBound = -10;
int upperBound = 10;
int n = 10;
boolean needPositive = true;
while (result.size() < n) {
    int nextValue;
    if (needPositive) {
        nextValue = random.nextInt(upperBound + 1);
    } else {
        nextValue = random.nextInt(upperBound) + lowerBound;
    }
    if (result.add(nextValue)) needPositive = !needPositive;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Насчёт быстрее не уверен, но решение красивое.